# Map elements in angular 6

Tags: javascript, angular

[image: ERROR]JSON

```
{ success: true, data {...}, calendar {...}
```

Component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MonthlyViewService} from "../../../monthlyView.service";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private  monthlyViewService: MonthlyViewService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.monthlyViewService.getMonthlyData().subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.map(res => res.data);
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

In Above code,i want access data,calendar data from response and store it into different array. I'm getting error on map - map does not exist on type object .
Any solution

Comment: Can you show `getMonthlyData()` method and what it is returning?

Comment: Can you console the ``res``? a=nd post what you get from it?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, since RxJs 6, you have to import operator like this:

```
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

Secondly, you have to use `pipe` before `map`:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.monthlyViewService.getMonthlyData().subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.pipe( map(res => res.data) );
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
```

Comment: added image and used u r snippet now it giving error on pipe same pipe does not exist on type object

Answer (score 2):

1. Map Operator of RxJs

According to official documentation for Map operator of RxJs,

> The Map operator applies a function of your choosing to each item
>   emitted by the source Observable, and returns an Observable that emits
>   the results of these function applications.

```
yourOservableCall().map(res=>res.json()).subscribe(data=>console.log(data))
```

2. Map function of array

> map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in this array.

```
var numbers = [1, 4, 9]; 
var roots = numbers.map(Math.sqrt);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is considering yourObject (res) is of type object. Which you can verify by printing the `res` itself.

It rightly says that `map()` doesn't exist on `Object` type. However, it does exists on `Array` type. So you could do the following ([Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)):

```
let data = Array.from(yourObject).map(arrayElement => {
  // do stuffs with arrayElement
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `res` as `any` type. Then if `map` does exist in the type of actual response you will not get that error hopefully.

```
this.monthlyViewService.getMonthlyData().subscribe((res:any) => {
      let data = res.map((res:any) => res.data);
      console.log(data);
    })
```

Hope this will work for you!

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MonthlyViewService} from "../../../monthlyView.service";
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-calendar',
  templateUrl: './calendar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calendar.component.css']
})
export class CalendarComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private  monthlyViewService: MonthlyViewService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.monthlyViewService.getMonthlyData().subscribe(res => {
      let data = res.pipe(map(res =>
      res.data);
      )
      console.log(data);
    })
  }
}
```

There was a major update in usage of Observables in rxjs. The functions like map, catch etc should be now used a pipe and catch changes to catchError  etc.

For more details 
https://www.academind.com/learn/javascript/rxjs-6-what-changed/